# VBA - How can I loop through rows looking for 2 values that could be in any column

Tags: excel, vba

VBA - How can I loop through rows looking for 2 values that could be in any column, if it finds the two values in the same row then highlight the row. In this case I need to highlight if the row has Inspector and Receiver in the row. This sheet is nearly 10,000 Lines.

[Sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Vo3.png)

Here is what I have so far. It allows me to loop through and highlight for one value but not two.

```
Sub Highlight_Conflicting_roles()
endrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Row In Range("A5:A" & endrow)
If Row.Value = "Inspector" Then
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.Match`, `Range.Find`, or `WorksheetFunction.Countif`? You can also do this with conditional formatting btw.

Comment: Ill try the Range.Find, thank you for the quick response. I know it can be done with Conditional Formatting but since the values move and i would like this to be repeatable the VBA is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Many options, here's one:

```
Sub Highlight_Conflicting_roles()
    Dim endRow as Long
    endRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 to endRow
        If Application.CountIf(Rows(i), "Inspector") > 0 And _
           Application.CountIf(Rows(i), "Receiver") > 0 Then
            Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ben this looks as if it would work perfectly for me, sadly when I attempted it I got no error but also no result. I will continue to bang my head against this, thank you again for being so helpful.

Comment: @PeterRees - my bad, should have been `> 0` rather than `> 1`... can you try the revised code?

Comment: Oh man Ben, you are really a genius! I tried to up-vote your solution but I guess I'm a insignificant worm. Thank you again!